# Must $T:V \to V$ be the $0$ transformation if $\langle T(v),u\rangle=0 \forall u,v \in V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Must $T:V \to V$ be the $0$ transformation if $\langle T(v),u\rangle=0 \ \forall u,v \in V$?

My intuition say $T$ must be the $0$ transformation, can someone give me a formal proof please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick $u=T(v)$, then this implies $T(v)=0$ for all $v\in V$.